# Problem with Neyman-Pearson lemma p-value

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing, p-value

The problem that I'm working on is this:

> We've got a random sample of iid $X_1, ..., X_n$ with distribution $N(\mu,1)$ and let $S_n=X_1+...+X_n$. Find the significance level (p-value) for $S_n$ testing $H_0: \mu = 3$ and $H_1:\mu=6$, for $n=4$ and $S_4=15$.

So far I've used the Neyman-Pearson lemma and got this result:
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^4 x_i\geq\frac{logK}{3}+18\hspace{2mm}$ if my calculations are correct.

And from there I don't know how to continue, I guess I should use $S_4$ somehow. I've been thinking about dividing everything by 4 and then I'll get some inequality for $\overline{x}$.

Comment: Have you found your test statistic and its distribution under $H_0$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom I wasn't sure for the test statistic if it's $z=\cfrac{\overline{x}-\mu_0}{s/\sqrt(n)}$ wchich in  my case is probably $(3,75-3)/(\sqrt(4)/\sqrt(4))$. I think that $\overline{x}=S_n/4$ and maybe $s$ is the standard deviation for $S_n$ which is sum of normal distributions. And if it's that than how to find the distribution under $H_0$?

Comment: A suitable form of the test statistic is $\sqrt n(\overline X-3)$, whose distribution under $H_0$ is something you should be able to tell. There is no $S$ in this expression because the population standard deviation is known, so you don't have to estimate it using the sample standard deviation $S$.